# Сравнение двух массивов и возврат индекса

Tags: javascript, массивы, сравнение

есть два массива - arr1 и arr2, в каждом один элемент - одни символ (разбиты на символы в общем) 
нужно их сравнить. Если есть какой-то символ, который существует и в arr1 и в arr2, то должен вернуться его индекс в массиве arr2(а лучше чтобы сразу вернулся его инкремент)

Так то пишу на Javascript, но можете дать ответ на любом другом ЯП - мне это тоже поможет

Comment: Добавьте этих два массива сюда, один - весь алфавит (от А до Я), другой - массив из одной буквы. И поставьте задачу: вернуть номер буквы в алфавите от 1 до 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нужно воспользоваться банальной `indexOf(arr2[0]) + 1`:

```js
let alphabet = [...'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'];
let massiv = ['а'];
let index = alphabet.indexOf(massiv[0].toLowerCase()) + 1;
console.log(index);
```

Интерактив (если не буква русского алфавита, то 0, -1 возвращает indexOf):

```js
let alphabet = [...'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'];
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let p = document.getElementById('p');

let putToP = () => {
    let massiv = [...input.value];
    p.textContent = massiv.map(b => alphabet.indexOf(b.toLowerCase()) + 1).join(' ');
};

input.addEventListener('input', putToP);

putToP();
```

```html
<input placeholder="Введите букву" value="АбвГд" id="input">
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: либо это не работает, либо я не так объяснил поставленную задачу и мне нужно другое. У меня есть массив - там весь алфавит от А до Я. Так же есть массив, в котором лежит, допустим, один символ (одна буква из алфавита). Необходимо, чтобы мне возвращался номер этой буквы в алфавите(ее индекс в первом массиве, увеличенный на один, тк массивы начинаются с нуля). Надеюсь сейчас я объяснил правильно.

Comment: @theorr теперь работает?